# Create a Custom loading indicator in nuxt 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I want to create a loader that appears between path changes, and not the one that appears with

```
<NuxtLoadingIndicator :throttle="0" :height="2" class="bg-orange-100 z-[500]" />
```

to achieve a screen load.

I have tried to create a component /components/CustomComponent.vue

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.4.8/vue.global.min.js"></script>
<template>
  <div class="loader" v-if="isLoading">
    <div class="spinner"></div>
    <p class="message">{{ message }}</p>
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts" setup>

const {isLoading,message} = defineProps({
   isLoading: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true
    },
    message: {
      type: String,
      default: 'Loading...'
    }
})
</script>

<style scoped>
.loader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

.spinner {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid #ccc;
  border-top-color: #333;
  animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
}

.message {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #333;
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
</style>
```

and in the app.vue I put

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.4.8/vue.global.min.js"></script>
<template>
  <CustomLoader v-if="$nuxt.isLoading" />
  <NuxtLayout>
    <NuxtPage />
  </NuxtLayout>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
const nuxtApp = useNuxtApp();
const loading = ref(false);
nuxtApp.hook("page:start", () => {
  loading.value = true;
  console.log(loading.value);
});
nuxtApp.hook("page:finish", () => {
  loading.value = false;
});
</script>
```

but when I switch between routes or change routes the loader does not appear, I hope you can help me.

Regards.

Comment: Is that a 'typo' mistake? "/components/CustomComponent.vue" and then using <CustomLoader />

Comment: Try to bind the prop like `<CustomLoader v-if="$nuxt.isLoading" :is-loading="$nuxt.isLoading" />`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I have added it as you indicated, but it does not appear.